# maximum and number of distinct real roots

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)=x^6+2x^5+bx^4+x^3+bx^2+ax+1$ and $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)\neq 0.$ Then maximum number of distinct real roots of $f(x)=0,$ is

what i try: $x^6+2x^5+bx^4+x^3+bx^2+ax+1=0$

$x=0$ in not a solution

$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+\bigg(2x^2+\frac{a}{x^2}\bigg)+b\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)+1=0$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: For $a=2$ it is simple, take $x+1/x=y$,

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

If $f(1)=0$ then the sum of the even and odd coefficients differ only by sign. That is, $2b+2=-(a+3)\to a=-2b-5$

Comment: Yes. $a=-2b-5$. But how does that help in establishing that the polynomial has at most 4 real roots? Descartes Rule of Signs does not seem to help.

Comment: It aids factorisation. $$f(x)=(x-1)(x^5+3x^4+(b+3)x^3+(b+4)x^2+(2b+5)x-1)$$

Comment: Yes. We knew that $x=1$ is a root. So the question can also be phrased as finding the maximum number of real roots of that quintic. But the quintic has no obvious factorisation. So I don't see that we are any further forward.